# Foreign Keys Relation - Unique tuple

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have a 3rd table that stores data from two other tables...

```
fk_first_table | fk_second_table
1 | 1
1 | 2
1 | 3
1 | 4
2 | 1

...
```

How can I assure that both keys never repeat...
Forming a unique tuple...
Kind of unique together like a table of truth.

Comment: The combination of columns could be treated as the primary key; `CREATE TABLE ThirdTable ( fk_first_table INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES first_table, fk_second_table INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES second_table, PRIMARY KEY(fk_first_table, fk_second_table))`.  Alternatively, you can change `PRIMARY KEY` to `UNIQUE` to have the DBMS enforce a uniqueness constraint without making the combination the primary key (which would be relevant if some other column or columns form the primary key).

Comment: Great! I didn't expected such a simple and genial solution...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON tbl_name (fk1, fk2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a unique index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indexName ON thirdtable (fk_first_table, fk_second_table)
```